# Ubuntu 18.04 showing a zoomed in screen

Tags: display, display-resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Pc, after fresh installation the screen seems to be zoomed in. Everything is big, I checked for resolution menu and found that the biggest resolution I can get is 1024*764. I tried a solution from a blog

http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html

It works, but just for that single session after I reboot the pc, everything comes back.
(maximum resolution my screen can take is 1366*768)

My screen is also not recognized by the system